# Updating Ruby 2.2.3 to Current

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I received a ruby on rails application that was written three years ago 
(Rails 4.2.1)

I need to update everything to current version of ruby, rails, rvm, bundler, rbenv, gems, etc...

Please help on process to achieving the update and the app to run not only locally but live.

Comment: And the author responsibly wrote wall-to-wall automated tests, right? And they all still pass with the 10-year-old stack installed, right?

Comment: I don't think he wrote any automated tests, all I know it is still live and working.

Comment: I would start a new Rails app with the latest Ruby, and use Test Driven Development to port the old app over, line by line. Write a test that fails, copy a line out of the old app, pass the test, integrate & deploy, and repeat until all the features are installed - with tests. Anything else is just playing in the mud.

Comment: Philip. Please example more about Test Driven Development.

Comment: TDD is where you write a test that fails, run it and make sure it fails for a correct, predictable reason, and only then add the production code that passes the test. Only integrate if all the tests pass. Learn more about TDD at its original web page: http://wiki.c2.com/?TestDrivenDevelopment . Learn to TDD in Rails by reading its flagship book, /Agile Web Development with Rails/

Comment: thank you I will read about TDD. The app still works! but if I update anything it brakes

Comment: I think the point Philip is making is that _if_ there had been thorough test coverage, then you could perform your updates, and if all the tests pass you're golden. He is also insinuating that there are spotty tests at best and you do not have the luxury of that solution, hence his recommendation to go line by line.

Comment: is this all done locally?

Comment: Yes! no test coverage. I just don't know what to do! I'm so confused with this project directory.

Comment: I'm insinuating there are no tests at all, and the only recourse is to start fresh and build the app line by line, under TDD, using the original app as just a big cheatsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what your ruby in now

```
$Ruby -v
```

Update it to ruby version 2.3.7

```
$rvm list known
$rvm install 2.3.7
$rvm use 2.3.7 --default
$gem install bundler
```

Let me know if does that help!

Comment: followed your advice. 
since I am also updated Rails 4.2 to 5.2. Do I need to change ActiveRecords to ApplicationRecord?

Comment: @Stephanie Check out this video about how to update your ruby version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsNXc3uQ2AA&lc=z22pvls4asawvhi5004t1aokgq0e4p2vb1qpp3w3z252bk0h00410.1528974099408204

Answer (score -1):

Hey dude upgrate from a very old to newest versions requires a lot of patient and skills. I found an article that might help you and also helped me before. I hope it can help you. Let me know if you have any more doubts

[Upgrade ruby on rails project](https://nandovieira.com/upgrading-a-project-to-the-latest-ruby-on-rails-version)

Comment: So I'm still updating Rails. currently to 5.0.7.... error with the strong params. 
ActionView::Template::Error (Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as changing the host. Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be secure.):

Answer (score -2):

Start a new Rails app with the latest Ruby, and use Test Driven Development to port the old app over, line by line.

Write a test that fails, copy a line out of the old app, pass the test, integrate & deploy, and repeat until all the features are installed - with tests.

TDD is where you write a test that fails, run it and make sure it fails for a correct, predictable reason, and only then add the production code that passes the test. Only integrate if all the tests pass. Learn more about TDD at its original web page: wiki.c2.com/?TestDrivenDevelopment . Learn to TDD in Rails by reading its flagship book, /Agile Web Development with Rails/.